# Magento 2.4.1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageTemplate' of undefined

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1

My Magento store was working fine before updating to the latest version of Magento then I started getting this error and now none of the images load and the checkout doesn't work anymore.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageTemplate' of undefined

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'uiComponent'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.template = window.checkout.imageTemplate || this.template;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: there might be another issue other than that. you can check from the logs

Comment: Okay! I will check the logs and see